# Output Data To outFile For Each Execution(Java)

Tags: java, output, printwriter, file-io

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Temperature
{
        static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        double Celsius;
        double Farhenheit;

        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("tempConversion.out");

        System.out.print("Enter a temperature in degrees Farhenheit: ");
        Farhenheit = keyboard.nextDouble();

        Celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (Farhenheit - 32.0);

        System.out.println("Farhenheit: " + String.format("%.1f", Farhenheit));
        System.out.println("Celsius: " + String.format("%.1f", Celsius));

        outFile.println("Farhenheit: " + String.format("%.1f", Farhenheit));
        outFile.println("Celsius: " + String.format("%.1f", Celsius));
        outFile.close();
        }
    }
```

I have this simple temperature conversion program that outputs the data to the screen, as well as an outFile.

How would you make this program write an outFile for each execution of the program?

Example: Instead of rewriting "tempConversion.out" to display new information for each execution of the program, it would have to write a new file for each set of data; such as "tempConversion1.out", "tempConversion2.out", ect.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a loop, with a counter starting at 1. At each step, check if file "tempConversion"+counter.toString()+".out" exists using [File.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html). If it exists, increment the counter; if not, break out of the loop and write to that file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createTempFile` method from `File` class.

```
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(File.createTempFile("tempConversion",".out","/path/to/the/directory"));
```

That will create a new, unique file name which will begin with "tempConversion" and end with ".out" in `/path/to/the/directory` directory.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) for more details.